# Coding an approximation sequence recursively. DrRacket, Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket, sequence, approximation

<sup>Very recently, a question was asked, ["How to find mistake in my sequence. DrRacket, Scheme"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47800720/how-to-find-mistake-in-my-sequence-drracket-scheme), and then deleted by an impatient asker.</sup>

<sup>Since I was in the process of typing the very few last words of my answer, here it is reposted, the Q and the A, so that it won't go to waste.</sup>

<sup>Here it is quoted *almost* verbatim:</sup>

---

I am trying to solve this sequence:

[image]

I am doing it in a `do` loop, the condition of stop-expression is

[image]

But my `do` loop doesn't work. I can't find a mistake. Please, help me. My code:

```
(define (y a n x )
  (if (= n 0)
  a
  (* 0.5 (+ (y a (- n 1) x) (/ x (y a (- n 1) x))))
  )
  )
(define (f a x e)

 (do
  ( (n 0 (+ n 1)) )  


( ( < (abs (- (sqr (y a n x)) (sqr (y a (- n 1) x)))) e) ("end of loop")) 

(display (y a n x))
(newline)

)
 )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indentation is your friend, not your enemy:

```
(define (y a n x)
  (if (= n 0)
    a
    (* 0.5 (+      (y a (- n 1) x) 
              (/ x (y a (- n 1) x)) )) ))

(define (f a x e)    
  (do ( (n 0 (+ n 1)) )  
      ( (< (abs (- (sqr (y a    n    x)) 
                   (sqr (y a (- n 1) x)) ))
           e) 
        ("end of loop")) 
    (display (y a n x))
    (newline)))
```

This code is pretty unusual in its approach. It reminds of *iterative deepening* in Prolog. You are trying to solve it in gradually increasing number of steps.

Put differently, you calculate the *n*th and the *(n-1)*th member of the sequence in isolation. But really, it takes just one step to go from the latter to the former.

---

Here is the situation where recursion is not your friend.

Corecursion, i.e. iteration, is your friend here.

Instead of counting from *n* down to *0* on each step, while incrementing the starting value of *n* before each step all the time;

```
0
1 0
2 1 0
3 2 1 0
....
```

why not just simply count *up*, from *0*, in increments of *1*:

```
0 1 2 3 ....
```

going boldly forward until the condition holds?

But what do we care how many steps did it take to reach the solution? We don't! We don't need `n` at all.

Not to mention that `(- 0 1)` is a value which your  function `y` is forced to deal with, by the `do` loop in `f`, yet is not equipped to handle, leading to bottomless recursion. And that's just the one issue that jumped at me from your code; there's more (a string is not a function), but really, the code needs to be overhauled anyway.